# While loop with sed

Tags: linux, bash, loops, while-loop

I have the following code but it doesnt work when i execute the code, the file th2.csv its empty.
The function of the sed is replace two words. I dont know how to make the script work correctly.
*It must be done with the **while***.

```
bash th1.csv > th2.csv
```

Script bash

```
 #!/bin/bash
   while read -r line; do
       echo "$line" | sed -E "s/,True,/,ll,/g;s/,False,/,th,/" th1.csv
    done < th1.csv
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do here. Why have a loop that reads from `th1.csv` and then echo's the line to sed which also reads from `th1.csv`... I can't figure out what `th2.csv` has to do with any of this. What do you think `bash th1.csv > th2.csv` is going to do?  Are you just wanting to do: `sed -E "s/,True,/,ll,/g;s/,False,/,th,/" th1.csv > th2.csv` ? If that isn't what you are trying to do, then can you explain, in english, exactly what you want to accomplish with these two files and bit of `sed` code?

Comment: @JNevill Yes, but with a while. I dont know how to make it work

Comment: Your loop is useless, since it's given a file parameter `sed` ignores its standard input. Just use `sed -E "s/,True,/,ll,/g;s/,False,/,th,/" th1.csv` in the script (or replace the script call by  `sed -E "s/,True,/,ll,/g;s/,False,/,th,/" th1.csv > th2.csv`). I'm not sure that'll fix your problem but it will at least simplify it

Comment: @Aaron No, it's a must to be done with a while even if it is not  the "proper" way of making it.

Comment: @Ktrm *"it's a must to be done with a while even if it is not the "proper" way of making it"* **WHY?** Is this homework? If so, please state that so we can help you solve within the constraints of the homework. Otherwise no one is going to suggest a solution using a `while` loop for something that absolutely doesn't need it.

Comment: @JNevill It isnt homework, it's a side project and the guidelines told us to make a regex over a csv.I have been trying to look for any possible solution in stackoverflow and other forums until I have come to the conclusion that it does not make any sense to do it this way because of the way sed works. But it's still the way the manual says we should do it, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Gotcha. It's homework-like in the sense that you are bound by some specification that may not be the "Right" way of doing it, but you are bound none-the-less. Makes sense. That clarification is helpful.

Comment: You are feeding `sed` with two sources: The standard input coming from the pipe, and by explicitly naming a file (th1.csv). You have to decide for either one or the other.

Comment: `the guidelines told us to make a regex over a csv`, sais nothing about a `while`. Or use `while :; do oneliner_sed_from_jnevill; break; done`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the requirements that you must loop and apply regex, line by line, then consider:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
   echo "$line" | sed -E "s/,True,/,ll,/g;s/,False,/,th,/" >> th2.csv
done < th1.csv
```

This reads, line by line, via a while loop. Each line is passed as stdin to `sed`. Note we remove the `th1.csv` at the end of your original `sed` attempt, as that will override `sed` reading from stdin (causing it to ignore it and instead process the file over and over again, every iteration). Lastly we append `>>` to your `th2.csv` file each iteration.

---

Guessing a step ahead, that you may want to pass the two files in as parameters to the script (just based on your first code snippet) then you can change this to:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
   echo "$line" | sed -E "s/,True,/,ll,/g;s/,False,/,th,/" >> "$2"
done < "$1"
```

And, assuming this script is called `myscript.sh` you can call it like:

```
 /bin/bash myscript.sh 'th1.csv' 'th2.csv'
```

Or, if you make it executable with `chmod +x myscript.sh` then:

```
 ./myscript.sh 'th1.csv' 'th2.csv'.
```